# Symfony2 translate URL and Routing

Tags: url, routes, symfony, translate

I'm trying to translate my url routing in Symfony2.

I already manage that the tld change the language of my application.

Ex:

- domain.com => local="en_US"
- domain.fr => local="fr_FR"
- domain.it => local="it_IT"

The translation is working for static word in template with
`{% trans %}Hello %name%{% endtrans %}`
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html#translations-in-templates

but I'm trying to translate the routing.

Ex:

- domain.com/user      => FrontBundle:Default:user
- domain.fr/utilisateur => FrontBundle:Default:user
- ...

All url going to the same action

I didn't find a good way to do it with Symfony2

ps: I saw this post [Zend translate URL and language switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947756/zend-translate-url-and-language-switcher) it's quite the same problem but with Zend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle:

https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle

Comment: This Bundle seem to be made for me but I can't find the doc to see which locale is use for the translation.
I use Symfony 2.1.0-DEV and there is no locale in this class. the locale is in the Request. But the Bundle dont see the change and use the translate fallback

Comment: Doesn't seem to maintained anymore.